Vertical spacing in beamer class
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength\lineskip{0pt}
\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\vskip}{0pt} % This line ensures that vertical skips are removed
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt} 
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

{\bf\color{blue}Title 1}

{\bf\color{blue}Title 2}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
    % Faded rectangle
    \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,3em);
    % Opaque text
    \node[anchor=west] at (1cm,1.5em) {\color{red}\bfseries\huge Title 3};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \color{red}\Large\textbf{Title 4}
\end{frame}

I am working with the above code and would like to have more control over the vertical spacing between lines and objects in beamer. In particular, how would I reduce the vertical spacing between two lines (e.g. between Title 1 and Title 2) and between the blue banner and Title 4 to be 0? This seems to already be the case between Title 2 and the blue banner, but I haven't been able to get it consistent for the other lines. Any help is appreciated, as always. 

Off-topic: you shouldn't use two letter font macros like \bf with latex

You can use \nointerlineskip to remove the normal space between two lines:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

\begingroup
\bfseries\color{blue}Title 1

\nointerlineskip Title 2
\endgroup

\end{frame}

\end{document}


